# How I can manage the state for 4 Checkbox in functional component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I would create a functional component with exactly 4 checkboxes? I have created dynamically mapping an array and I set its value with:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([false, false, false, false])
```

and then, with a function I change its state, something like:

```
const checkboxes = array.map( (el, index) => {

return <Checkbox

checked={checked[index]}

onChange={checkedHandler}/>

}
```

This is the handler:

```
const checkedHandler = (event, index) => {

setChecked(...)

//Well, here I don't know how change the particular value of the array...

}
```

Or I must create a useState for each Checkbox checked state? And how pass the state of this Checkbox to the father component if it was necessary?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the checkedHandler wrong way. You have:

```
onChange={checkedHandler}
```

And you should have:

```
onChange={() => {checkedHandler(index)}}
```

In the handler itself you should copy your current array to prevent its mutation and change the value of the `indexed` one:

```
const checkedHandler = (index) => {
  const newChecked = [...checked];
  newChecked[index] = !checked[index]; // toogle the checkbox
  setChecked(newChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign `id` to each checkbox like `id="1"`, `id="2"` and so on...

Then your `checkedHandler()` function be like:

```
checkedHandler(event) {
    const newChecked = [...checked]
    newChecked[parseint(event.target.id) - 1] = true
    setChecked(newChecked)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is ALOT of ways you can do this, if you case is simple, you could just shallow copy the array and change only the index you want.

```
let newChecked = [...checked]
newChecked[index] = value
setChecked(newChecked)
```

But for more complex cases, please take a look at [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)